# Static Local Variable of a Template `inline` Function

Tags: c++, templates

`static` local variables of an `inline` function in C++ are guaranteed to exist as if being a single global variable, if my understanding is correct.

Does the same apply if the `inline` function is a template, where the compiler can generate multiple versions of the function?

Comment: There is now way to have a global `inline` variable in multiple libraries (or a template `inline` variable in multiple translation units). There is no standardized linking.

Comment: @DieterLücking Do you mean that the `inline` variable proposal was accepted to be included in the next standard?

Comment: @xiver77: No clue - can you provide a link

Comment: @DieterLücking You said "there is now way to have a **global inline variable** in multiple libraries".

Comment: A template function is not a function.  It is a template for producing functions.  Each set of template arguments (not function arguments) produces a distinct function.  The rules around `inline` apply to each such function instance.  Is that is what you are asking about?

Comment: @shuttle87 A static member is very different from a local static.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following article should answer you question very well: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/templates-and-static-variables-in-c/

In short: The Compiler produces one static variable for each template.

If you want to have the same variable for all templates you can maybe try something like this:

```
int& hack()
{
  static int i = 10;
  return i;
}

template <typename T>
void fun(const T& x)
{
  int &i = hack();
  cout << ++i;
  return;
}
```